# Подключение к облаку из проводника

Tags: облако, windows

Как подключиться к облачному диску в проводнике Windows? Есть Skydrive/DropBox, недавно зарегистрировался на яндексДиск и Гугле (жду подтверждения). В яндексе пишется, что можно с проводника заходить и работать как будто это обычный сетевой диск... но пока не могу проверить. Может в других службах можно как-то это сделать, не "лазя" в веб интерфейс, а работая, например, в тотале?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Yandex.disk и Windows 7.

Запустить "Проводник". Выбрать меню "Сервис", "Подключить сетевой диск".В открывшемся окне нажать ссылку "Подключение к сайту, на котором можно хранить документы и изображения.". Запустится "Мастер добавления сетевого размещения". Жмём "Далее". Жмём на выбор "Выберите другое сетевое размещение". Жмём "Далее". Вводим адрес в поле "Сетевой адрес или адрес в Интернете".

https://webdav.yandex.ru

Жмём "Далее". Вводим свои пароль и логин. Обязательно отмечаем пункт "Запомнить учётные данные", иначе их придётся на каждый чих снова и снова вводить. Жмём "Далее", "Далее" и "Готово".

Всё, Яндекс.диск подключён, пользуйтесь.